# PySpark methods math.max, math.ceil error name 'math' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following functions with the following math methods:

math.max and math.ceil.

```
def dp():
  defaultParallelism  = spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism
  return defaultParallelism

def files(dp, multiplier, ram, target):
  maxPartitions = math.max(dp * multiplier, math.ceil(ram / target).toInt)
  return maxPartitions
```

When I execute the following lines of code:

```
targetMb = target(128)
maxPartitions = files(defaultParallelism, 2, ramMb, targetMb)
```

I get the following error message:

NameError: name 'math' is not defined

The full error is as follows:

```
---->  maxPartitions = files(defaultParallelism, 2, ramMb, targetMb)

---->  maxPartitions = math.max(dp * multiplier, math.ceil(ram / target).toInt)
```

Any thoughts on what could be the problem?
I think its because of the math.max, and the math.ceiling

Comment: do you import math?

Comment: ahhhhhhh.... no I didn't import math. Is the code for that ```from pyspark import math```?

Comment: ok, ```import math``` did the trick. Now I'm getting the error ``` module 'math' has no attribute 'max'```

Comment: ok, I've very nearly fixed this issue. The edited function ```def files(dp, multiplier, ram, target):
  maxPartitions = max(dp * multiplier, math.ceil(ram / target))
  return maxPartitions```
Now gives me the following error
```
TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: i didnt see anything wrong this the func, do you have other function that takes only one argument and you pass in additional one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was fixed when I removed the following modules:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
```

For some reason (I really don't know why) whenever any of the above modules were included in the code I got the error